# Why is TListView's Node text truncated with an ellipsis until I toggle ViewStyle?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Can anyone help me understand why the displayed labels for a TListView are truncated with an ellipsis at program startup, but are completely displayed after switching to vsIcon and back 
again?  I don't want any truncation or ellipse...

Edit 1: Columns[0].AutoSize is TRUE, MaxWidth is 50, Width is 50.

Edit 2: Left hand screen capture corrected so source text is the same as the right side's.

TIA

[image]

Comment: I don't know, but this is an interesting question :)  Bookmarked.

Comment: What version of Delphi and Windows are you using?  Themed app, or unthemed?  Does changing this make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Below posted an answer on the Embarcadero forum (https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=45670&tstart=0) pointing to an identical question asked a year ago here: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=27079.

Synopsis is to manually set the column width:

```
    Uses CommCtrl;

    ListView_SetColumnWidth( listview.handle, 0, NewWidthOfColumnInPixels );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ViewStyle=vsReport, make sure you have a column defined whose Width is large enough to accomodate your longest text value. TListColumn.AutoSize does not always work correctly, especially when the Listview is intially loaded.